# Parse HH:mm:ss and H:mm:ss for LocalTime using single DateTimeFormatter in java8

Tags: java, datetime, java-8

I am trying to parse **08:24:55 (HH:mm:ss)** and **8:24:55 (H:mm:ss)** using `LocalTime.parse()` method in java 8. Below Code successfully get's executed and prints **08:24:55**:

```
LocalTime time=LocalTime.parse("08:24:55", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss"));
System.out.println(time);
```

but the same set of code fails for input **8:24:55** and throws error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '8:24:55' could not be parsed at index 0

Any suggestions what could be done to handle both scenarios?

Comment: Maybe you could do a conditional pattern based off the length of the string?

EG: if(timestr.length() == 8){ pattern= "HH:mm:ss"; } else if( timestr.length == 7){ pattern= "H:mm:ss"; }

Comment: @zack6849, no need for that. See the much simpler solution in the answer.

Comment: @OleV.V. you may notice my comment was before Juan's answer, in fact I upvoted his answer once I saw it, I see no reason to delete my comment, however.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use just one `H` in your pattern:

```
LocalTime time= LocalTime.parse("08:24:55", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H:mm:ss"));
```

Output:

> 08:24:55

Answer (score 1):

You can make some "times" optional via:

```
 DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("H[H]:mm:ss")
```

Comment: This is rather a bad idea because the optional part will never succeed and just causes a performance penalty. Leave it out and be happy with "H:mm:ss".